# Problems with create a new ImageGenerator

Tags: module, kinect, openni

I'm new to the OpenNI and I'm trying to create a simple ImageGenerator that just display a pure color image, say white, I modified the “SampleModule” and in the UpdateData() method I assign the *pPixel value with 255. The UpdateData() method is as following

```
XnStatus SampleImage::UpdateData()
{
    XnStatus nRetVal = XN_STATUS_OK;

    XnUInt8* pPixel = m_pImageMap;

    for (XnUInt y = 0; y < 300; ++y)
    {
        for (XnUInt x = 0; x < 400; ++x, ++pPixel)
        {           
            *pPixel = (XnUInt8)255;
        }
    }

    m_nFrameID++;
    m_nTimestamp += 1000000 / SUPPORTED_FPS;

    // mark that data is old
    m_bDataAvailable = FALSE;

    return (XN_STATUS_OK);
}
```

The code compile fine, and I could register it with nireg, but when I try to read the image pixel value from the data generated by the module I got some strange value (not 255 as I expected), I use the following code to read the pixel value.

```
const XnUInt8*    pImageMap = mImageGenerator.GetImageMap();

for (XnUInt y = 0; y < 300; ++y)
{
        for (XnUInt x = 0; x < 400; ++x, ++pImageMap)
        {
            cout << (int)*pImageMap << endl;
        }
}
```

and also when I run the “NiViewer” the program still say it can't find the image node, but the “SampleModule” can be find as a depth.

Any advice would be appreciate.

Thanks a million,
Haolin Wei

Comment: so when u run NiViewer, and press 1 or 2 or 3 or 4... do you see images? or not?

Comment: Hi blueskin, I have tried the niviewer but it said it can't find the device, I think it might because the configure file, but I don't know why the "SampleModule" that comes with the openni runs fine in the niviewer after register. Any suggestions? Thanks a lot.

Comment: I am using a older version of OpenNI so not sure what the SampleModule is. if you open your device manager, do you see anything like Xbox NUI Camera or something along those lines.?

Answer (score 0):

Check if you did following things:
1. set color format, i.e, rgb (or YUV)
2. set correct value for each pixel in the updataData(), i.e. r=255,g=255,b=255